# i want to develop a dynamic url lake google max , when i send ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, turbolinks

in search/index.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

in search.js

```
var lat = 17.0123;
var lng = 28.0124538;
var position =  new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
var zoomLevel = 8;
var mapId = document.getElementById('map');
var map;
function initMap(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapId, {
  center: position,
  zoom: zoomLevel,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
}
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

       var map_centre = map.getCenter();
       lat = map_centre.lat();
       lng = map_centre.lng();


     }

});//idel function end
```

Now i want to get the dynamic url of zoom level and latitude and langitude of map using turbo links in my rails project.
Can you help me how to do?

Comment: Can't you get it directly from the browser address bar after running the project? Or another way is to Use the "Element" option in the chrome browser by right clicking the webpage and select "inspect" and finding the URL over there.

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude from "share your location" javascript. Just i want to send parameters to a particular action and get response , to change  a particular div which is google map div without reloading whole page. I referred  (https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) and tried.Can you help me how to replace particular div @Aniv . Thank you.